# Missing packages when installing .deb via dpkg -i

Tags: package-management, lubuntu, dependencies, citrix

I'm attempting to install Citrix Receiver on a fresh install of Lubuntu. Being a flavor of Ubuntu, I figured it'd be safe to ask this here.

I run:
`sudo dpkg -i icaclient_13.10.0.20_amd64.deb`

and I get the following

```
(Reading database ... 243579 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack icaclient_13.10.0.20_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking icaclient (13.10.0.20) over (13.10.0.20) ...
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of icaclient:
 icaclient depends on libwebkit-1.0-2 | libwebkitgtk-1.0-0; however:
  Package libwebkit-1.0-2 is not installed.
  Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not installed.

dpkg: error processing package icaclient (--install):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.23-3ubuntu2) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.60ubuntu1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 icaclient
```

I don't see these exact packages show up in the Muon Package Manager. 
So, my question is: **what is the safest way to go about installing these packages without breaking my OS?**

```
Package libwebkit-1.0-2 is not installed.
Package libwebkitgtk-1.0-0 is not installed.
```